# Add WYSIWYG to Image Description field

Tags: custom-field, images, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

I need to build this thing:

[image]

It's essentially an image with a caption, and it can go inline anywhere in the text. I could just create a shortcode for it I suppose, but I'd really like to integrate it with the Image Picker to make it easier for my clients.

Is there any way to either add TinyMCE to the Description field, or otherwise add a custom TinyMCE field to the image picker?

Thanks.

Comment: sometimes wordpress stack exchange can be a peculiarly deserted place, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: It's been quite a while, I don't even remember what project this was for. I'm pretty sure I just ended up using HTML in the field.